# Errors in jquery while using it with django

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tokeninput

I get a

> Uncaught TypeError: field.tokenInput is not a function

error on my console on this javascipt file djtokeniput.js. Here is the code in the file-

```
jQuery(function() {
jQuery("input.tokeninput").each(function() {
var field = jQuery(this);

field.tokenInput(
  field.data("search-url"),
  field.data("settings")
);
});
});
```

It is using this file to get the tokenInput function which is made a plugin. jquery.tokeninput.js- 
this is the tokeninput code snippet-

```
// Expose the .tokenInput function to jQuery as a plugin
$.fn.tokenInput = function (method) {
// Method calling and initialization logic
if(methods[method]) {
    return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
} else {
    return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
}
};
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Try putting the `jquery.tokeninput.js` snippet inside `jQuery(function() { ... }` and put `jquery.tokeninput.js` before `djtokeniput.js` in the dom?

Comment: @Ignaus now I get a Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined in jquery-tokeninput-1.6.0-min.js:10 also in djtokeninput.js:1 and the same error as above.

Comment: @Ignaus  I played around with DOM now i only get the error i was originally getting.